# After opening a new tab in Selenium WebDriver, how to make it the visible/active tab in my browser?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, tabs, webdriver

I am using the following WebDriver Java code to open a new tab (granted there are possibly better ways to do this) :

```
        WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.id("home_button")); 
        Actions newTab = new Actions(driver); 
        newTab.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).click(link).keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();
        ArrayList<String> openTabs = new ArrayList<String> (driver.getWindowHandles());
        driver.switchTo().window(openTabs.get(1));
        driver.navigate().to("http://google.com");
```

And it works perfectly well, and any further actions I do are applied to that new tab, but it is not visible on my screen, I can still see the first tab that was opened. Is there any way to change which tab is visible in my window?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For switching tabs, use

```
newTab.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,Keys.TAB)).perform();
```

Comment: I tried the above, unfortunately I could still see my original tab.

Comment: Yes, because this just switches you to a new tab.. Do you need to delete the previous tab or what ?

Comment: I want the tab that I switch to to be the one I can actually see in my window.

Comment: Okay just replace the above code using this: `newTab.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,Keys.F4)).perform();` It will close the currently opened tab, which I presume is the original tab, before clicking and opening the new tab.

Comment: @Subh F4 will close the tab itself

Comment: @VigneshParamasivam : It will close the currently opened tab. So, all that will be left is the new tab that has opened, after doing a "Control-Click" as the OP wants.

Comment: Yeah that closes the tab, I want to have them both open.

Comment: @Ash: Then use the original code, i.e., `newTab.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,Keys.TAB)).perform();` to switch back and forth between the tabs. Use this first time to switch to newly opened tab. Then, use it next time to switch to the former one.

Comment: @Subh But that doesn't actually change which tab is visible in my window for some reason. It doesnt seem to do anything.

Answer (score 1):

**Actually, switching between tabs is fine. But switching control in-between them, is not possible** because even if you open a new tab it is still inside the main window, and unless you close the original tab, the control won't shift to a new one.

**So, what you can do is open the link in a new window, and get the window handle of the newly opened window. Then, you can switch between the two windows (alongwith switching handles) and perform the necessary action(s).**

Below is an example using "google.com" site. Please execute the code and check the flow. You will understand what I meant above:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public class Testing_window_switching{

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException{

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); //Opening firefox instance

        driver.manage().window().maximize(); //maximizing window
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //Giving implicit timeout of 20 seconds


        driver.get("http://google.co.in/");

        driver.findElement(By.id("gbqfq")).sendKeys("stackoverflow");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@role='listbox']//div[.='stack overflow']")).click();

        String parentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();//Getting parent window handle
        System.out.println("Parent Handle is: "+parentWindow);


        Actions newTab= new Actions(driver);
        WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='srg']//a[.='Stack overflow - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia']"));
        //Opening the link having text 'Stack overflow - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia']' in new window
        newTab.contextClick(link).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();

        String childWindow = null;
        for(String childs: driver.getWindowHandles()){
            if(!childs.equals(parentWindow)){
                childWindow = childs;
                break;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Child handle is: "+ childWindow);

        driver.switchTo().window(childWindow); //To switch handle to child window   

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[.='Stack overflow (disambiguation)']")).click();
        driver.navigate().back();

        newTab.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.ALT,Keys.TAB)).perform(); //To switch to main window
        driver.switchTo().window(parentWindow); //To switch current handle to parent
        System.out.println("Switched to parent window");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='srg']//a[.='Blog – Stack Exchange']")).click();// Click on the link 'Blog – Stack Exchange' in parent window

        newTab.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.ALT,Keys.TAB)).perform(); //To switch to child window.  
        driver.switchTo().window(childWindow); //To switch current handle to child
        System.out.println("Switched to child window");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='n-mainpage-description']/a")).click();//Clicking on the link 'Main Page' in the Child window

        Thread.sleep(10000);//Sleep time of 10 seconds, not necessary but just to give some time before quitting

        driver.quit(); //Closing all instances of browser

    }
}
```

Comment: @Ash: Please let me know, if you don't understand what's happening in the code above.

Comment: Almost a year later - Switching control two the currently active tab is done with this: driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent(). Also, I switch between tabs by sending: Ctrl + (Tab Number). That way you can either loop or go directly to a tab.

Comment: That's ingenious! Thanks a lot @BClaydon . You made my day..  :)