# Unable to switch between two browser windows using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am new to WebDriver, i am facing an issue on browser window switching.
I googled for my query resolution and the answer i found best is still not working for me.

Here is my code :

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeSuite;


public class FrameWorkBase {

public static WebDriver driver;
    public static WebDriverWait wait;
public static String firstWindow,secondWindow;
    @BeforeSuite
    public void startDriver() throws Exception{

driver= new FirefoxDriver(); // this firefox window is to open survey
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        wait=new WebDriverWait(driver, 40);

        driver.get("http://www.cricinfo.com");
firstWindow=driver.getWindowHandle();

driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        driver.get("https://translate.google.co.in/");
secondWindow=driver.getWindowHandle();


        System.out.println("First window handle :" + firstWindow);
        System.out.println("\n Second window handle :" + secondWindow);

driver.switchTo().window(firstWindow);
System.out.println("hello");
}
}
```

I am getting an error on execution as Unable to find window 'xyz' where 'xyz' is the name of first window.
Even i am printing the window name and it is displaying the same window for which it is displaying error.

Please suggest me what i am doing wrong here.
Thanks

Comment: Please refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19117747/how-to-switch-between-two-windows-in-browser-using-selenium-java

Comment: The answer provided there is the same i used, is it necessary to close the other browser window for navigation? That answer is not helpful for me. :(

Comment: Not necessarily. As long as you have the handle of both the Parent and the Child window, you can navigate back and forth and perform actions on either of them. Please check my answer below related to that. Hope it helps you in gaining some ground on this. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you have reinitialized the driver instance.

```
driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://translate.google.co.in/");
```

This line has reinitialised your driver instance so what ever u try to do you won't find the window handle. If you are trying to work on both websites simultaneously, try to create another object of driver like `WebDriver driver2 = new FirefoxDriver();`

Answer (score 0):

@Vivek has aptly answered your question. But, if you still want to open a link in a new window, you can try the below code for that:

```
Actions act = new Actions();
WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//xpath of the link"));

//Opening the link in new window (works in FF and Chrome)
act.contextClick(link).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
```

**And you can switch in between them accordingly, with the use of handles. Furthermore, [this link will help you handle two windows simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27187171/after-opening-a-new-tab-in-selenium-webdriver-how-do-i-make-it-the-visible-tab/27190106#27190106)**.