# Why won't Selenium WebDriver switch to my new tab that is an excel report

Tags: java, eclipse, excel, selenium, webdriver

I have used this method below many times in other scenarios and it focuses on my newly opened tab just fine. 
Now I have link to an active excel report that gets loaded into a new tab when i click on it, and my code below is not changing focus to that newly loaded tab. I am not sure why because control tab still works in the browser, so shouldn't it still work in my code? Any help as to why my code is not focusing on my newly opened excel report tab would be great help. 
Thanks!

```
public void mymethodnameishere (WebDriver driver) {
        System.out.println("Starting mymethodnameishere method");
        Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(mylocatorishere));        
        action.contextClick(driver.findElement(mylocatorishere)).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
        action.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(Keys.TAB).perform();
        System.out.println("mymethodnameishere method completed successfully");
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than opening in a new tab, open the **excel report** in a new window because **selenium can't switch handles across two tabs to work on both of them** as both belong to the same window. Even if you do a switch across the tabs using **"CTRL+ENTER"**, I am afraid the focus won't shift from the original tab. If you **open the report in a new window**, you will be able to switch in between them using the respective window handles.

Below Java code will help you in opening the report in a new window:

```
action.contextClick(driver.findElement(mylocatorishere)).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
```

Also, please go through this link, where I have stated an [**example for working with 2 windows simultaneously**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27187171/after-opening-a-new-tab-in-selenium-webdriver-how-do-i-make-it-the-visible-tab/27190106#27190106)

Answer (score 0):

I actually found another way to make it work within the tabs, without having to open windows. The focus shifted to my newly opened excel report by just adding the same line below. Now it works fine.

```
action.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(Keys.TAB).perform();
```

Final Working Code Below:

```
    public void mymethodnameishere (WebDriver driver) {
            System.out.println("Starting mymethodnameishere method");
            Actions action = new Actions(driver);
            action.moveToElement(driver.findElement(mylocatorishere));        
            action.contextClick(driver.findElement(mylocatorishere)).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
            action.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(Keys.TAB).perform();
            action.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL).sendKeys(Keys.TAB).perform();
            System.out.println("mymethodnameishere method completed successfully");
```